# Running C++ using clang++ in VScode terminal (The value of miDebuggerPath is invalid)

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, clang++

I'm new to using C++ and have been trying to figure this out for hours. I'm using windows. I installed VScode, the extension for C++, installed MSYS2, and set up clang++. Now I'm trying to run file hello.cpp in VScode using their terminal. It's just hello world. When using the below task, it executes but then throws "Unable to start debugging. The value of miDebuggerPath is invalid." The hello world does not output and I'm at a loss. **Does anyone know why this is happening and have suggestions on how to fix?** Thank you and much appreciated!

[Here is a pic of the commands I've been trying to run in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQlsw.png)

Executing task: C/C++: clang++.exe build active file <

Starting build...
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\clang++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\test\hello.cpp -o C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\test\hello.exe

Build finished successfully.

**My code**

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
std::cout << "Hello World!";
return 0;}
```

**My launch.json**

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": []}
```

**My tasks.json**

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: clang++.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\clang++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    },
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    },
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: clang-cl.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\clang-cl.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    },
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: clang-cpp.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\clang-cpp.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    },
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"}
```

Comment: Your launch.json is empty and has the very clear clue *For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387*

Comment: I got this because I installed MSYS2 (which doesn't have a debugger by default?) instead of MinGW (which does)